# Unable to store geojson in mongodb 2.4 with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geojson

**UPDATE: solved by renaming my model attribute "loc" instead of "location"**

I'm having trouble saving a user location in mongodb 2.4.x with mongoose in a node.js app. I have the following set up:

Mongoose model:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    location: { 
        type: { type: String },
        coordinates: [Number]
    }
});

UserSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });
```

node.js/mongoose

```
var userId = "30303030303";
var geoJSON = { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [4.4662489999999995, 51.169115999999995] };
User.findById(userId, function (err, user){
       user.location = geoJSON;
       user.save();
});
```

This triggers the following error:

```
[MongoError: Can't parse geometry from element: location: "[object Object]"]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'Can\'t parse geometry from element: location: "[object Object]"',
  code: 16700,
  n: 0,
  connectionId: 449,
  ok: 1 }
```

After updating my model like Peter says, the error is now the following:

```
err: 'location object expected, location array not in correct format',
```

Has anyone experienced something similar or does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try defining the coordinates schema as `coordinates: [Number]`. Also, I might remember mongoose considering "type" a reserved word so you may need special treatment to tell mongoose that you really want to define a property named "type" not declare the type of your mongoose schema.

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said. The error is now "err: 'location object expected, location array not in correct format'" like you can see in my updated questions.

Comment: Solved it by renaming the field "location" to "loc"

Comment: "location" is a reserved word in Mongo ?

Comment: post your answer as an ANSWER!!